# Relation between centripetal and tangential acceleration and Newton's Second Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So I was solving a simple rollercoaster kind of problem and I wasn't getting anywhere because the acceleration had two components, a radial one and a tangential one. The objective was to express the normal force has a function of the height. 
I consulted the answer and they applied $$F = ma$$  $$mg - n = m \frac{v^2}{R}$$
The answer clearly considers only the radial component of the acceleration on the Second Law formula. Is this correct? Can I ignore the tangencial component when applying the Newton's Second Law?

Comment: Are you sure your acceleration had two components? Don't you mix it up with the velocity?

I guess you should check your forces again.

Comment: The forces acting on the coaster are the normal force and the gravitational force. The gravitational force creates a tangential acceleration, am I correct?

Comment: Tangential to what? The coaster rails? Is it tangent all along?

Comment: The loop is vertical, so there is a tangential acceleration all along the movement, right?

Comment: $\vec F=m\vec a$ is a vector equation.

Comment: Tangential means that the force is colinear with the rails (with the motion of the mass actually). Gravity only pulls down as far as I guess. So in your loop you have a downward component which happens to be tangential at some points and radial at other. I think you should rethink about your problem a bit.

Comment: Member for 5 years. Last seen more than 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I ignore the tangencial component when applying the Newton's Second Law?

**Yes you can**, because the force you are looking for (the normal force) will only influence the radial component. There might be other components of acceleration, but they are not caused by and have no influence on the normal force.

We must remember in these cases that Newton's 2nd law is a vector equation:

$$\vec F=m\vec a$$

Vectors consist of coordinates:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}F_x\\F_y\end{matrix}\right)=m\left(\begin{matrix}a_x\\a_y\end{matrix}\right)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\left(\begin{matrix}F_x\\F_y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}ma_x\\ma_y\end{matrix}\right)$$

Adding all forces at a point on the roller coaster curve:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}w_x\\w_y-n\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}ma_x\\ma_y\end{matrix}\right)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\left(\begin{matrix}w_{tan}\\w_{rad}-n\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}ma_{tan}\\ma_{rad}\end{matrix}\right)$$

Remember that in vector equations, coordinates are equal to each other and not interfering with one-another. The left-hand-side x coordinate equals the right-hand-side x-coordinate etc. We pick out the y coordinate equation, since that is where $n$ appears:

$$w_{rad}-n=ma_{rad}\quad\Leftrightarrow\\
mg\sin(\theta)-n=m\frac{v^2}R\quad\Leftrightarrow\\$$

Many other things might or might not happen at the x coordinate. But they are irrelevant in a talk about a y directional force.

Since the solution in your textbook omits the $\sin(\theta)$, it must be because $\sin(\theta)=1$, meaning that we are at the top where $\theta=90^\circ$. They surely have a reason for this, which is not clear from the question - might be a step on their way towards the result to start at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you wrote applies neither at the very top of the loop nor at the very bottom of the loop.  At the top of the loop, the force balance is $$mg+n=m\frac{v^2}{R}$$where n is the normal force exerted by the rail.  At the bottom of the loop, the force balance is $$n-mg=m\frac{v^2}{R}$$  At these locations, the component of gravity in the direction tangent to the loop is zero.

At all other locations around the loop, gravity has a component tangent to the loop, and, to determine how the velocity v is varying around the loop, you must also include the component of the force balance in the tangential direction.

Comment: If the OP's equation holds, depends on the situation. If the roller coaster is on top of (and not on the bottom side) of the track at the top point of the loop, and driving slow, the normal force will indeed point upwards, gravity downwards and radial acceleration downwards.

Comment: If the normal force points upward, all that means is that n is negative, and the rail is exerting a tensile force on the roller coaster.  By convention, the normal force is  considered positive if it is compressive in the direction from the body that is exerting the force to the body that is receiving the force.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the example I gave. The point is that the question doesn't describe the situation. It could be a roller coaster being thrown around the inner side of a loop and thus having a normal force downwards - and then the expression given is not possible, as you state - but it could also simply be a roller coaster rolling uphill over the loop as a wagon over a hill, just fast enough to get over the top, without being "pulled downwards" by the rails - then the normal force is positive upwards and gravity positive downwards, and the expression given fits fine.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I see what you're saying.  In any event, if one wishes to determine the variation of v with time, one would have to also include the tangential force balance.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration in [a frenet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) is$$\mathbf{a}=\frac{dv}{dt}\,\mathbf{t}+\frac{v^{2}}{r}\mathbf{n}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

$\frac{1}{r}$ the curvature of the trajectory.

For a uniform circular motion $r=R$

Newton's second law

$$\sum _{i} \mathbf{F}_{i}=m\mathbf{a}=m\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{R}$$
for perfect connection; there are
no frictional forces. The reaction is reduced to its normal component $R_{n}$.

from (1)

$$m\mathbf{g}.\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{R}_{n}.\mathbf{n}=m\frac{v^{2}}{r}$$
$$mg\cos({\theta})-R_{n}=m\frac{v^{2}}{r}$$
for a circular trajectory:$$mg-R_{n}=m\frac{v^{2}}{R}$$

Comment: According to a student of Alexandre Grothendieck, the first lessons were about choosing the right notation to express ideas...